UTF-8 replacement characters between every character when reading file in PHP
I've written some code to parse a tab-delimited file and import it into a MySQL table. The file is UTF-8, as is the MySQL table.
The import works, but when I view the data in a field in my table, every other character shows as the UTF-8 replacement character of �. For example, the number 4308817 in the raw file shows up in the database as "4�3�0�8�8�1�7".  I do have some UTF-8 characters (like ë and so forth) in the data, so that is required.
I've tried all sorts of things with utf8_encode, decode, mb_convert_encoding, etc and nothing seems to make these show up without the � characters.

$lines = file($dir . '/' . $file);
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    $arr = explode("\t", $line);
    if($line_num > 0) {                                 
        $idx = 0;
        $AddSQL = "INSERT INTO `$table` VALUES(";                   
        foreach ($arr as $field) {
            $value = $arr[$idx++];
            $AddSQL .= "\"" . str_replace('"', '\"', trim($value)) . "\", ";
        }
        $AddSQL = substr($AddSQL, 0, strlen($AddSQL) - 2);
        $AddSQL .= ")";
        
        $dbconn->query($AddSQL);
    }
}


This problem isn't new. A useful question/answers can be: UTF-8 all the way through

I think it's a problem with the data. Can you paste an example row somewhere like https://3v4l.org/?

@YourCommonSense - I'm not familiar with that site, and don't see an obvious usage for checking the data.  How would it be used for that? Thanks!

Or, better, add this line to your code if ($idx == 1) echo bin2hex($value), " "; below $value = $arr[$idx++]; and simply paste the result here in the comment

Looks like the file is UTF-16LE encoded…

@YourCommonSense - That gave me back "0049006c006c0075006d0069006e006100740069006f006e00"

@JosefZ - I had that thought at one point, but attempting to treat it as UTF16 did not solve it. I should also mention that mb_check_encoding($line, "UTF-8") returns true for every value.

Any bytes <= 0x7f are valid UTF-8 characters, but your data are truly UTF-16 encoded.

@shingo If that is the issue,  can you suggest the proper method for handling?

Can you save your file with UTF-8?

Or when reading convert each line to UTF-8: mb_convert_encoding(). PHP can do this in various ways.

@KIKOSoftware - It does seem to be the file. If I create a fresh UTF-8 file and paste the data into it with Ultra-Edit, and save that - the new file runs through the process and works as expected.  If I use mb_convert_encoding($line, "UTF-8", "UTF-16LE") on the original file, however, I end up with lines full of chinese characters: 䤀氀氀甀洀椀渀愀琀椀漀渀ऀ

Looks like I just found the solution by stumbling onto this function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/uconverter.transcode.php
mb_convert_encoding did not work for me, but this did:
$line = UConverter::transcode($line, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');


OK, but just to be sure, is it UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE? These have different byte-order encoding schemes. So a $ is 00 24 in "BE" or big-endian and 24 00 in "LE" or little-endian. Then it is not surprising, when you use the wrong one, that you end up with Chinese characters.
